# Regular expression: match at least *two* of a given list of strings or patterns?

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, preg-match

Suppose I have defined a list of colors. I can check whether at least one of these colors occurs in a string with a regular expression like this:

`(red|orange|yellow|green|cyan|blue|magenta|white|gray|black|transparent)`

Is it also possible to make a regex pattern to check if **at least two** of the above colors occur?

(not: the same color more than once, but actually **two different** colors i.e. two different matches from the list of patterns)

I can think of trickery to achieve this, such as: finding the first match, removing all instances of that match (i.e. search/replace it with an empty string or something) and then perform the regex check again. If it matches again, I know there is a second color.

But is there a more sophisticated way of doing this, preferably 'regex only'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the first color in a group, and then right before matching the second color, negative lookahead for a backreference to the first color matched:

```
(red|orange|yellow|green|cyan|blue|magenta|white|gray|black|transparent).*(?!\1)(red|orange|yellow|green|cyan|blue|magenta|white|gray|black|transparent)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ubR2HF/1

Or, if your engine can recurse a prior group, it can be written more DRY:

```
(red|orange|yellow|green|cyan|blue|magenta|white|gray|black|transparent).*(?!\1)(?1)
```

You can continue the pattern for additional colors by capturing them in groups, and using negative lookahead for all groups previously matched:

```
(red|orange|yellow|green|cyan|blue|magenta|white|gray|black|transparent).*(?!\1)((?1)).*(?!\1|\2)(?1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ubR2HF/2

Comment: Amazing, I never knew about this syntax in regex. Great to learn something new, thanks!